# Error using 2 wcf services with methods that require the same class as param

Tags: c#, wcf, service-reference

The error is referenced in the comments of ***Client Demo Code***

**Service 1 Demo Code**

```
    [ServiceContract]
    public interface IService1
    {
        [OperationContract]
        Boolean AddPerson1(Person p);
    }
```

**Service 2 Demo Code**

```
   [ServiceContract]
   public interface IService2
   {
       [OperationContract]
       Boolean AddPerson2(Person p);
   }
```

**Client Demo Code**

```
Person p=ServiceReference1.Person{Name="Peter"};
new Service2Client().AddPerson2(p); //Error right here because the method requires ServiceReference2.Person
```

**Error Message**

[image]

I need to be able to use Person from ServiceReference1. Maybe Class cast would solve the problem but i am not allowed to do it

**ServiceReference1 and ServiceReference2 Settings**

[image]

Comment: Do the 2 WCF services share the same `Person` class? If not, then what you are trying to do will not work. You've got 2 different Person classes on the client for each service. And those 2 classes have nothing in common.

Comment: @DarinDimitrov Yes, in the 2 WCF services the Person class is the same

Comment: Is Person class defined on each WebServices or Person class defined on your application?

Comment: @IkramTurgunbaev The 2 WCF services are on the same WCF Application and both use the same class Person

Comment: Can you post the actual error message?

Comment: Note that `ServiceReference1.Person` and `ServiceReference2.Person` will be viewed as two different classes even if they have the same code because of the namespace difference.

Comment: As @Tim said in your case you should use `Person` class with its `namespace` for each `serviceclient`

Comment: @Tim I have added the error message

Comment: @IkramTurgunbaev According with my ServiceReference1 and ServiceReference2 Settings, am i not supossed to be able to reuse them? 
I have red [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb628653(v=vs.100).aspx) in order to reuse them.

Comment: It's ok, but error says that `ServiceReference1.Person `and `ServiceReference2.Person` are different. May be something missed

Comment: Where is `Person` defined?

Comment: @Tim The 2 WCF services are on the same WCF Application and both use the same class Person but when adding the service references  looks like 2 distinct Person class are created but i would like to be able to reuse them as written [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb628653(v=vs.100).aspx)

Comment: If the `Person` class and the WCF services are all part of the same assembly, then `Person` class will not be shared across the services.  `Person` would need to be in a separate assembly to be reused, and even then I think the namespaces of the two services would cause problems, unless, the client is also using the assembly that has `Person`.

Comment: @Tim Thanks. I will accept your answer. You could also add your last comment on the answer to help other noobs like me :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message is clear:

> Argument 1: cannot convert from
>   `WpfApplicatoin1.ServiceReference1.Person` to
>   `WpfApplication1.ServiceReference2.Person`

The objects are **not** the same, even if the code is the same, because of namespaces.

You'll need to map from `WpfApplication1.ServiceReference1.Person` to `WcfApplication1.ServiceReference2.Person`, or put the `Person` object in a separate assembly that is shared by the services and the client.

For example, if you were to map between the two you might have something like this:

```
Person p = ServiceReference1.Person{Name="Peter"};
ServiceReference2.Person p2 = new ServiceReference2.Person() {
    Property1 = p.Property1,
    Property2 = p.Property2,
    // and so on
};
new Service2Client().AddPerson2(p2);
```